# update crypto-config.yaml file and update in the network

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Is there a way to update the crypto-config.yaml file and then update it over the network without bringing the network down in hyperledger fabric 1.4.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. What changes do you want to do in crypto-config.yaml?

Comment: I am making changes to the crypto-config.yaml while the network is still running. So i will need to re-generate the crypto-config folder right?

Comment: Does my post answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend your existing fabric network like adding a new peer, then first create artifacts for it.

Adding a new peer:

1. Increase the peer count in `crypto-config.yaml` by increasing the value of `Template`.
2. Generate certificates for new peer nodes using `cryptogen extend --input="crypto-config" --config=config.yaml`

where,

```
--input="crypto-config"  The input directory in which existing network place
--config=CONFIG          The configuration template to use
```

1. Add the docker configuration for the new peer and CouchDB(if statedb=couchdb), then run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-new-peer.yaml up -d new_couchdb_container new_peer_container`.

You won't have to bring down the whole network to add a new peer node.

Refer to [this](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217) for more information on *how to add a new peer*.

Comment: You can always create fabric identities using fabric-node-sdk if you're using SDK. Otherwise, you can do it using `fabric-ca-client` binary which is available in fabric-ca container.

Comment: But if while creating the network initially we mention the number users in the crypto-config.yaml. But later on if we would want to add more users than the once we mentioned would the farbric-node-sdk

Comment: So for example bellow is the part of my crypto-config.yaml file:
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1

So the count of users is 1. And i went ahead and enrolled 1 user. Now i would like to add more new users. Do i need to create the channel artifacts and crypto file again?